# Problem with altitude value in iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have problem when i try to get altitude value in from iPhone to my application.

Please give me some solution. My code is here:

```
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
//NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(newLocation.altitude)];
double value = [newLocation altitude];
NSLog(@"test= %f",value);
```

Code is always written 0.0000 in NSlog.

Comment: are you testing it in simulator?

Comment: How do you create `newLocation`? A zero probably means that it's not defined.

Comment: Location print like <+43.02333587, +82.53887516> +/- 80.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2011-04-20 10:41:06 +0530 from (null)

Answer (score 0):

The `altitude` value is pretty unreliable. It is only available if your location has been determined with GPS and even then it is usually a lot more inaccurate than the lat/long location.

In your example, the horizontal accuracy of +/– 80m suggests that the location fix has not been determined with GPS or that GPS reception is not very good in that area. Be sure to check the location's `verticalAccuracy` as well. If it is a negative value, the `altitude` value will have no meaning whatsoever.